# Install SITL Error: what am I missing?

Tags: dronekit-python, dronekit

I am stuck with getting the SITL to install and I have tried many ways.
Please I don't know how to proceed.

I followed the instructions in
http://dev.ardupilot.com/wiki/sitl-nati ... _in_cygwin

I am able to
make px4-v2

The paths are set correctly in .bashrc
export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/ardupilot/Tools/autotest

However,
make sitl -j4
generates the following error:

```
$ make sitl -j4
%% libraries/AP_Common/c++.o
%% libraries/AP_Common/AP_Common.o
%% libraries/AP_Menu/AP_Menu.o
In file included from /home/Me/ardupilot/libraries/AP_Common/c++.cpp:9:0:
/home/Me/ardupilot/libraries/AP_HAL/AP_HAL.h:6:21: fatal error: stdbool.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
C:/cygwin/home/Me/ardupilot/mk/build_rules.mk:27: recipe for target '/tmp/arducopter.build/libraries/AP_Common/c++.o' failed
make: *** [/tmp/arducopter.build/libraries/AP_Common/c++.o] Error 1
make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
In file included from /home/Me/ardupilot/libraries/AP_Common/AP_Common.cpp:21:0:
/home/Me/ardupilot/libraries/AP_HAL/AP_HAL.h:6:21: fatal error: stdbool.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
C:/cygwin/home/Me/ardupilot/mk/build_rules.mk:27: recipe for target '/tmp/arducopter.build/libraries/AP_Common/AP_Common.o' failed
make: *** [/tmp/arducopter.build/libraries/AP_Common/AP_Common.o] Error 1
// BUILDROOT=/tmp/arducopter.build HAL_BOARD=HAL_BOARD_SITL HAL_BOARD_SUBTYPE=HAL_BOARD_SUBTYPE_NONE TOOLCHAIN=NATIVE EXTRAFLAGS=-DGIT_VERSION="c52f16b8"
In file included from /home/Me/ardupilot/libraries/AP_Common/AP_Common.h:26:0,
                 from /home/Me/ardupilot/libraries/AP_Menu/AP_Menu.cpp:7:
/usr/include/stdlib.h:16:20: fatal error: stddef.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
C:/cygwin/home/Me/ardupilot/mk/build_rules.mk:27: recipe for target '/tmp/arducopter.build/libraries/AP_Menu/AP_Menu.o' failed
make: *** [/tmp/arducopter.build/libraries/AP_Menu/AP_Menu.o] Error 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Easier to use vagrant for doing this than doing manually : http://ardupilot.org/dev/docs/setting-up-sitl-using-vagrant.html

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes

Answer (score 0):

I use Ubuntu. Download the code and run it using the following steps.

```
git clone https://github.com/ArduPilot/ardupilot.git 
cd ardupilot
https://github.com/ArduPilot/ardupilot.git
make sitl -j4
```